# displaying a php file in an iframe using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe

Good day guys, I'm trying to learn codeigniter and I'm having a trouble displaying a php file in an iframe. Here's my code. It returns "404 Page not found"

here's my view:

```
<iframe class="tabContent" name="myIframe" src="<?php echo site_url('pages/view_about');?     >" marginheight="8" marginwidth="8"></iframe>
```

then here's my controller:

```
  function view_about(){

    $this->load->view('pages/about');
}
```

here's how my folders are arranged

application->views->pages->about.php

application->contollers->pages.php

I would just like to add, the code I pasted above for my view is located in

application->views->templates->footer.php

the iframe is actually a part of my footer thanks

Comment: Try inserting the URL to the broser, it'll probaby don't work as well. Check what URL is outputed to the Iframe

Comment: post the contents of pages.php in the controller..

Comment: I tried inserting this url in the browser http://localhost/projectname/index.php/about and it displayed the about.php

Comment: So `index.php/about` is not `index.php/pages/view_about`.

Answer (score 0):

php ending tag has space between

try this..

```
<iframe class="tabContent" name="myIframe" src="<?php echo site_url('pages/view_about'); ?>" marginheight="8" marginwidth="8"></iframe>
```

Comment: @pic-a if this link `http://localhost/projectname/index.php/about` works in browser you have to use `<?php echo site_url('about'); ?>`

Comment: thanks for the replies, I did what you say but when I put echo site_url('about') it displays the whole page inside my iframe

Comment: @pic-a change to `echo $this->load->view('pages/about','',true);` in your controller

Comment: I did what you said but still the whole page appears in the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please try below code hope it will work for you.

```
<a href="/pages/page" target="targetFrame">Page 1</a>
<iframe id="targetFrame" src="" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="NO" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried this but is not working, I changed pages/page with the location of my file but still didn't work